# Pressure difference inside a soap bubble when taking the limit $R \to 0$

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, surface-tension, fluid-statics

[image]The force exerted by a fluid on a surface normal to the fluid is:

$\pi R^2 \Delta p$ (1)

and the surface tension is:

$2\pi R \gamma$ (2)

and a sphere has two surfaces so, roughly:

$\Delta p = \frac{4 \gamma}{R}$

but if we take the limit:

$\lim_{R \to 0} \frac{4 \gamma}{R}$,

then obviously the pressure difference between the outside and inside surface of the bubble is $\infty$! How does that make sense? Is there any way I can get round this? Or have I done something wrong with my algebra?

Comment: You have done something wrong with your algebra.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yeah I assume so but I don't get what logical error I made! Everything makes sense to me :(

Comment: Why are you taking limit? You cannot have a soap bubble with zero radius.

Comment: @YashasSamaga Well it doesn't have to be zero but a radius of 0.000.....1 will produce a large value for pressure which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The limit of 1/x as x becomes infinite is zero, not infinity.

Comment: @ChesterMiller - But the limit of 1/x as x goes to zero is infinite.   Technically, Lewis is correct in that bubbles cannot have zero radius.  I recall doing a problem in undergrad or grad school where we showed that if one had an infinite volume of water and no dissolved solids/impurities, it would be impossible to form a bubble.  The way around this in real life are the curves/bumps/crevices on the walls of pots/pans in which one boils water.

Comment: Somehow I misread that it was asking for the limit at R infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is the Young-Laplace equation applied to a bubble in equilibrium.

Considering a non-equilibrium state in which $\frac{dR}{dt} < 0$ where $R$ is the radius of the bubble, the subsequent increase in pressure (as described by your equilibrium equation) will drive molecular diffusion of the gases inside the bubble to the outside of it (which can be thought of as acting to reduce the pressure in response to this increase). However, when enough gasses inside the bubble have diffused outward, the bubble collapses never really producing a bubble of near zero radius.